# Proof of the distribution of sample variance

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I'm reading *Probability and Statistics* by DeGroot and Schervish, and I got stuck on one particular line of the proof of the distribution of the sample variance $\hat{\sigma}$ of a random sample of $n$ many i.i.d. standard normal random variables $X_{i}$.  The sample has sample mean $\bar{X}_n$.

The equality that I can't follow is $(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2) - n\bar{X}_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2$

I understand that you can rewrite $n\bar{X}_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}_n^2$, which then turns the left term of the first equality to $(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2) - (\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}_n^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 - \bar{X}_n^2)$.  But for the life of me, I can't figure out how you get from that result to the right term of the first equality.  What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to go from right to left.

Note that $(X_i-\bar{X})^2=X_i^2-2X_i\bar X+\bar{X}^2$.

Summing, we get
$$\sum_1^n(X_1-\bar{X})^2=\sum_1^n X_i^2-2\bar{X}\sum_1^n X_i +\sum_1^n \bar{X}^2.$$
The middle term is $-2n \bar{X}^2$ because $\sum_1^n X_i=n\bar{X}$.  The last term is $n\bar{X}^2$.

**Remark:** I find it easier to see things by calling $\bar{X}$ by the name $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the expression being summed in $\sum_{i=1}^n \bar X_n^2$ does not depend on $i$, and thus it is just the sum of $n$ copies of $\bar X_n^2$; i.e. $n \bar X_n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... the difference between your two expressions is

$2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \bar{X}_n = \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sum_{j=1}^n X_j = \frac{2}{n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2$

but that could be nonzero. Something else must be missing.

Comment: Oh drats, didn't see that actually this is $2n \bar{X}_n$ as Andre has.